# Why is my error message body missing in the client exception while using RestTemplate in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, error-handling, jackson, resttemplate

I am calling a method called revoke in my project which in turn uses rest template to make http calls.

```
public revoke(String name){ 
   try{
    restTemplate.exchange(approveRevokeRequestEntity, String.class);
    }
catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ProcessException("Error while revoking!", e);
    }
}
```

This in called somewhat as follows:

```
try {
        client.revoke(name);
    }
catch (ProcessException e)   {

     log.info("Error Message is: {}",e.getMessage());   
     log.info("Cause Message is: {}",e.getCause().getMessage()); 
     if(e.getCause().getMessage().contains("already_revoked")) {
            log.info("Revoke request threw and Exception with expected cause, Continuing!")        
        }
        else {
            throw e;
        }
}
```

I know this throws exceptions for non 2xx response codes.

When I run this in locally in my IDE for a negative scenario, I get the following logs:

```
20:14:55.743 Error Message is: Error while revoking!
20:14:55.743 Cause Message is: 400 Bad Request: [{"errors":[{"code":"already_revoked","message":"Already been revoked."}]}]
20:14:55.743 Revoke request threw and Exception with expected cause, Continuing!
```

When I run this on the server, I get the status ("400 Bad Request") in the cause but the response body ("{"errors":[{"code":"already_revoked"....) is **missing**. As a result, the ".contains("already_revoked")" returns **false**, and instead of proceeding, the code terminates the process.

```
20:14:55.743 Error Message is: Error while revoking!
20:14:55.743 Cause Message is: 400 Bad Request
```

I am calling the same endpoint with the same credentials in both my local test and on the server. Not sure why I am not getting the error response body in the cause.

I even tried adding the following to my rest template but no success.

```
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(new ObjectMapper());
restTemplateForDigiCert.getMessageConverters().add(converter);
```

This is holding up my release, really need help here. 
Thanks!

Comment: Are all your libraries the same version on your local machine and the server machine? Spring, Jackson, etc.?

Comment: The server runs spring 4.3.23.RELEASE while locally it is 5.2.3.RELEASE. But even on using 4.3.23.RELEASE locally, I can get the cause message.

Comment: Not sure if it will help you here, but have you tried looking at the headers. You can do this by doing something like `restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(myLoggingInterceptor)` where `myLoggingInterceptor` is an Object which extends `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`. If you tried this from your IDE and on the server, you may see some difference?